# Inserting PHP code into Joomla article mixed with article HTML

Tags: php, html, joomla

I have this code:

```
<?php
$lastfile = null;
$files = glob('./images/fruits*.*');
foreach($files as $file) {
    $filename = pathinfo($file);
    $filepath1 = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
    $filepath2 = "images/fruits/".$filepath1;
    $base = basename($file, '.jpg');
    preg_match('#/([^/]+?)(?: \d+)?\.[^/]+$#', $file, $match);
    $filet = $match[1];
    if ($filet != $lastfile) {
       echo '{slider';
       echo '<strong>'.$filet.'</strong>|blue';
       echo '}';
       $lastfile = $filet;
       echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '{tip';
    echo "<img src=\"".$filepath2."\">";
    echo '}';
    echo "<img src=\"".$filepath2."\" "; 
    echo 'width="100" height="100" />{/tip}';
}
?>
```

It is running well. But I want to automatize that in Joomla article. I installed Sourcer extension for inserting PHP code into Joomla articles. Now everything is fine bexcept this:

```
echo '{slider';
echo '<strong>'.$filet.'</strong>|blue';
echo '}';
```

These lines must be a regular HTML article  (no PHP `echo()`) but in that PHP `foreach()` loop. Does anybody have idea how that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Sourcer, but if the php echo is the problem, try inline php:

```
...

if ($filet != $lastfile): ?>
   {slider<strong><?php echo $filet; ?></strong>|blue}
   <?php $lastfile = $filet; ?>
   <br>
<?php endif;

...
```

Thats just the lines you mentioned above. Probably you should write the whole page like that.

Comment: Thanks man thats that's it. I was googling also, to resolve how to break that few lines, but this really helped.